# How to convert file gerber extended .art to image or svg in php

Tags: php

I am working on a project that consists of a online web, to view Printed Circuit Boards.  and will be able to view online the Gerber files
Ex: SILK_TOP.art

How can I convert gerber files to svg or images using PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried [gerber-to-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gerber-to-svg)

Comment: I was wrong to orient it.
My purpose is to view it on the website.
I did it when I applied WebGL and ThreeJS.

Thanks,

Comment: convert the printed circuit Boards in the back end using geber-to-svc, save it in a folder which your application will bring using some http url